# Swift: How to use buttons in Scroll View

Tags: ios, swift, scrollview

I have created a scroll view with "buttons". But the "buttons" actually don't do anything at the moment. So, I would like to know, how I can make the "buttons" usable. So when I press them they lead me to a different view controller. All the buttons will lead me to the same view controller just with different data (depending on what I want that button to represent) inside the view controller. Here's my code so far:

```
     @IBOutlet weak var categoryScrollView: UIScrollView!
    var categoryArr = ["Button1","Button2","Button3","Button4","Button5", "Button 6", "Button 7", "Button 8", "Button 9", "Button 10", "Button 11", "Button 12"]
    var buttonColors = [UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.blackColor(), UIColor.cyanColor(), UIColor.magentaColor(), UIColor.greenColor(), UIColor.blueColor(), UIColor.blackColor(), UIColor.cyanColor(), UIColor.magentaColor(), UIColor.blackColor(), UIColor.brownColor()]
    let kPadding:CGFloat = 20

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let buttonSize = CGSizeMake(categoryScrollView.bounds.size.width/2, categoryScrollView.bounds.size.height/2)//hal

        let scrollingView = colorButtonsView(buttonSize, buttonCount: 12)
        categoryScrollView.contentSize = scrollingView.frame.size
        categoryScrollView.addSubview(scrollingView)
        categoryScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        categoryScrollView.delegate = self
        categoryScrollView.pagingEnabled = true
        categoryScrollView.indicatorStyle = .Default
        categoryScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0)
    }


    func colorButtonsView(buttonSize:CGSize, buttonCount:Int) -> UIView {
        let buttonView = UIView()
        buttonView.frame.origin = CGPointMake(50,300)
        let padding = CGSizeMake(kPadding, kPadding)
        buttonView.frame.size.width = (buttonSize.width + padding.width) * CGFloat(buttonCount)
        var buttonPosition = CGPointMake(0, padding.height)
        let buttonIncrement = buttonSize.width + padding.width
        for i in 0...(buttonCount - 1)  {
            let button = UIButton(type: .Custom)
            button.frame.size = buttonSize
            button.frame.origin = buttonPosition
            buttonPosition.x = buttonPosition.x + buttonIncrement
            button.setTitle(categoryArr[i], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
            button.backgroundColor = buttonColors[i]
            buttonView.addSubview(button)
        }
        buttonView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        return buttonView
    }
}
extension ViewController:UIScrollViewDelegate{
    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        let index = round(scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width)
        print(index)
    }
```

}

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "don't do anything", did you set a target/selector? Do they just don't respond to being tapped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create your button you have to specify a target in order to have an action with it (add this in your for loop) :

```
 button.addTarget(self, action: "myaction:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

then create the corresponding method

```
 func myaction(sender: UIButton!) {
// navigation code here.
}
```

Please note that you don't have to create several method in order to have different actions for each button, all you have to do is something like this :

```
 button.tag = i
```

and then in your action method :

```
switch sender.tag {

 case 0 : 
 //do some stuff

 case 1 :
 //do some stuff

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add targets to button to fire some action methods. Like in your loop when you create UIButton, add

```
button.addTarget(self, action: "pressed:", forControlEvents: .TouchUpInside)
```

and implement one method like:

```
func pressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    // navigation code here.
}
```

Comment: Do you know here I'd put this code? I'm having an error that says: 'View Controller' has no member 'addTarget'. putting it any where else besides the viewDidLoad method (which is what triggered the previous error) results in an error stating that there's no declaration.